# Regular Expression to match this string Pattern

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I am trying to construct a regular expression to match the following string patterns in a GWT (Java) program

The pattern must match strings in the following formats (Basically this is an address string that Im trying to send to Google Maps to get coordinates for:

```
"2205 someStreet, Miami, USA"
OR
"someStreet, Miami, USA" 
OR
"Miami, USA"
OR
"2205 somestreet Miami USA "
All other variations should not be allowed
```

So far I have tried these Regular Expressions

```
"([0-9a-zA-Z]+ ((\\s){0,1} | (,){0,1} (\\s){0,1}) [0-9a-zA-Z]$)+ "
"^[0-9a-zA-Z]+,|\\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+"
```

WHile they match some  acceptable string patterns they also match unacceptable string patterns.

So I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand with these.

Thanks

Comment: *What* unacceptable string patters are being matched?

Comment: one common mistake is to try and cram to many *exclusive* matches into a single regex. break this into 4 separate regex and the problem is very simple, to create and maintain.

Comment: Is this matching happening client side or server side? Client side of the portal has a restricted regex engine.

Comment: Do you really need to support a comma-free format (4th example)?  That will be a lot tougher, assuming you allow spaces in numbers, streets, cities, and countries (which you probably need to).  You may wish to gather a much larger set of sample data and look for existing address regex implementations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Google Maps APIs, but their UI already does a pretty good job of figuring out all those different address formats :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the simplest way to go would be to use 4 separate regular expressions instead of one monster complicated one which can go wrong more easily. (Plus if you use multiples you can add new acceptable patterns more easily.)

These patterns should work:

1. For "2205 someStreet, Miami, USA": `\d+ \w+, [A-Za-z]+, [A-Z]+`
2. For "someStreet, Miami, USA": `\w+, [A-Za-z]+, [A-Z]+`
3. For "Miami, USA": `[A-Za-z]+, [A-Z]+`
4. For "2205 somestreet Miami USA ": `\d+ \w+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+\s*`

I used `\w` for the street name to support numbered names like "12th".

Of course, these sentences assume that the city is only a single word. What if it's "New York"? It also assumes that streets are a single word -- "123 Broadway, Denver, USA" -- and won't support something like "123 West 12th Drive". You probably need to think a little more on what exactly constitutes a valid address.

The Google API's are usually pretty robust, so I'd expect the Google Maps API to be able to do a decent job of address format detection. There's a good chance you're just making extra work for yourself by trying to do this sort of validation.

Comment: +1 to not making things harder on yourself. Throw some addresses at the API and see how it handles it before trying to go it on your own. Also, might want to add capture groups to those regex's to make it easier to extract the fields.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Pea: Of course pattern 1 should be `\d+ \w+, [A-Za-z]+, [A-Z]+`.

Comment: D'oh. Typos get me every time. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Split you String with `,` *regex* then analyze the String[3] result step by step as you like.

*EDIT after comments*

You have also to analyze `String[].length` to decide for those with less than two `,`.

In this way you can have trailing spaces before/after the `,` you can remove with trim(), and you can focus on dedicated simple regexes.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, yes but you have only String[0] initialized